# Puppeteer to sign into TikTok

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer to sign into TikTok. However, each time I try to sign into TikTok with puppeteer it says "You are visiting our site too frequently" as pictured below.

[TikTok after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhCl6.png)

Here are the things I've tried:

- using puppeteer stealth
- using firefox puppeteer
- using both puppeteer stealth and firefox puppeteer
- using a VPN
- logging into the account on a different device, logging out on that device, and then running the code
- waiting 4 hours between running the code

Puppeteer doesn't throw any errors either

Let me know what you guys think!

Here is the code too:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.tiktok.com/login/phone-or-email/email");
  await page.type("input[name=email]", EMAIL, { delay: 20 });
  await page.type("input[name=password]", PASSWORD, { delay: 20 }); // log in w email and password

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector("button[type=submit]").click();
  }); // press login button

  await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: There can be any number of bot-dectecting techniques on their side. Try to launch puppeteer headfully and log in manually, will that work? Try to wait a few seconds before `page.goto` and `page.type`. Try another account.

Comment: I guess thay detect the number of log ins for that spesific username and password. If you tried to log in multiple times in a short period of time that might be the reason. If thats the case its better to get cookies from puppeteer browser and save it to a local json file using `fs` module. Then you can use it to automate the authentication process. Changing the user agent might help too.

Comment: @Vaviloff I put `await page.waitForTimeout(5000);` right after the `await page.goto()` and  I still got the same message from TikTok. I also tried with another account and still got the same error

Comment: @Sezerc I don't really know much about cookies and website authentication. I know that puppeteer has a way of getting all cookies so I was planning on using this method: `await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies')`. One question though. Which cookies should I get? Should I sign-in without puppeteer and download those cookies? Or should I download the cookies from the unsuccessful puppeteer trials?

Comment: I am not an expert about cookies too but i know that most websites uses cookies to remember your user authentication credentials.Which cookies should you get? I dont know either. It depends on website i guess. You need to get the cookies when you succesfuly logged in. Not when you get an error. Keep in mind that some websites uses localstorage instead of cookies.

Comment: We don't know for sure how to make it work, you will have to experiment, Zack. I concur with all points made by Sezerc, but there may be even more detections, like getting mouse movements for example or some puppeteer features not yet covered by extra stealth plugin. Can you log in manually in headful puppeteer?

Comment: That makes sense. I’ve noticed that the login doesn’t work with puppeteer, but when I do it manually on chrome it does work so I’m going to need to do more research. I am thinking of maybe using AppleScript (I’m on macOS) to do it through the chrome application but I’m not sure yet. Thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: @ZackBeucler Have you been successful?

Answer (score 0):

Log in manually one time and then do a cookie injection for each subsequent login :)

(of course, you'll need to save down all the cookies to do so, but only once!)